# Hosting multiple domains on the same website

Tags: redirect, iis-6, isapi-rewrite, isapi-redirect

In IIS 6, I need to allow multiple domains to come through to a single website so that they can all share the same master page and database. They would all have a uniform look. I own a separate domain name for each site. I need to know what is the best way of accomplishing this. I have read about ISAPI rewrite but don't really understand how that works. I have also considered just having a redirect statement based on the url. The websites each share the same purpose, but each one site is for a separate company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use host headers. One site can "answer" to many domain names.

[Using Host Header Names to Host Multiple Web Sites (IIS 6.0)](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/883a9544-3f70-4d46-a6df-bbadbd1fe7de.mspx)